# Go as backend API, Polymer frontend

Tags: api, go, polymer

I'm trying to work out the best way of getting Polymer to talk to my go app end points? I'm using Go and Postgres as the backend, but would like to use Polymer as the front-end instead of the Go html/template package. Has anyone got a good suggestion on how is set this up? Sorry, struggling to get the penny dropping on this part. I've watched Francesc Campoy's polymer-gopher video but it looks like he has the app setup already?

Also, would you recommend having go handle the routing also, or just be the data end point for this type of setup?

Thanks guys and gals :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you want to create a [single-page application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx) (img taken from this link):

- Go - backend (API)
- HTML/javascript (polymer) - frontend (static content)

[image]

In this scenario you don't need to use go [html/template](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/), basically you just create an API that in most cases will be returning [json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Your main concern by following this approach could be about how to secure your backend endpoints rather than need to deal with parsing templates, there are some options for this, [json tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction/) is one of them.

Comment: Thanks @nbari for taking the time to do this! That's a great answer :)